# Applying Decision Feedback Equalization to oversampled data

Tags: adaptive-filters

I am working on a system that simulates an encoded channel receiver in software.  I have a functioning symbol spaced  Decision Feedback Equalization (DFE) that works well to track the channel and estimate the output on a per-symbol basis - this is all working as expected.

The incoming and outgoing data stream is highly oversampled channel data, typically 200 samples per symbol.  I have to output the DFE corrected oversampled data stream for use in an eye diagram.  I am unsure of how to accomplish this.  Since the DFE is symbol based, I only update the error and tap weights once every 200 data samples.  Do I then apply this same correction to all of the sample points - i.e., add the same current DFE correction to every sample, or is it something more complicated?

Comment: For a clarification: do you need this only for the visualization of the eye diagram? Then you should in no case change the way the system is working "under the hood". Your eye diagram is anyway something that doesn't really "exist" in your system. I would try to use linear interpolation between the taps estimated at two symbols.

Comment: This is in the context of a network analyzer application.  We are generating a constellation, upsampling, adding noise and jitter, convolving with the system response of an arbitrary DUT as the channel, then equalizing and overlaying each symbol sequence to generate the high resolution eye diagram.

All of these operations until now have used the entirety of the upsampled signal.  The DFE is the first requirement that has to operate on both the N sampled data while only making updating at the 1/N symbol period.

Comment: Perhaps I can simplify this question somewhat -

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you've got some sort of "magic box" algorithm that takes in an actual signal $x_r$ and a hypothesized "perfect" signal $x_p$, and either gives you a system $\hat x = \hat h(x_r)$ that generates an equalized signal.

Note that this is the core of nearly all channel equalization schemes -- you have the actual received signal, the signal that you should have received, and the equalized signal, and you've got some adaptive filter that's trying its best to form an equalized signal that equals the signal you should have received.

So what you do, is that you use the *old* $\hat h(x)$ to generate the signal going into the bit slicer.  Then, once a decision is made, you regenerate the signal that should have been (the $x_p$), then you go *back in time* and update the $\hat h(x)$ using the values of $x_r$ that you stored away and the values of $x_p$ that you just found.

I don't have a whole lot of experience with adaptive filtering of this sort, but what experience I do have included doing something like what you're trying.  I found that trying to get a pretty signal by using way-oversampled values tended to make the equalizer function less well at the actual decision points for the bit slicer.  In my case I needed some "pretty" for the customer so I went ahead and kept the oversampling, but I put additional weight on the samples at the bit slice instants.